# Hi, i wanto to meake a program that give the position of a red ball in 2D with rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I already have a code in OpenCv for the detection and it works, i just dont know how to proceed with rviz. I see the camera in rviz by subcribing in the topic. But after that i dont know how to see it on GRID. Please does anyone can help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273792/hi,-i-wanto-to-meake-a-program-that-give-the-position-of-a-red-ball-in-2d-with-rviz/) by [ANDRO](https://answers.ros.org/users/32353/andro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-10-23**:
You need to tell RVIZ the position of your camera. You can do it with simple markers. But I would recommend doing it by publishing `tf` transforms of your camera (you'll probably need that anyway in the future).

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-10-23**:
Have a look at [tf_broadcaster](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29) tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So here you have very rudimentary solution. Of course you will need to add calibration procedures, and take extra thing into account like the blob area to get the distance value, but this I hope gives you a starting point.

So essentially you need to publish a Marker topic , with a Sphere Type of colour red. This marker will have to be referenced to your camera link or similar. I've done this Video as an example of how it could be done: [Video](https://youtu.be/OuYcJNlndsg)

The core about solving this is creating a script that retrieves your Detection Data and Publishes a Marker with it. Here you have the script I've used to publish it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from cmvision.msg import Blobs, Blob
from visualization_msgs.msg import Marker
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point
from sensor_msgs.msg import CameraInfo


class MarkerBasics(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.marker_objectlisher = rospy.Publisher('/marker_redball', Marker, queue_size=1)
        self.rate = rospy.Rate(1)
        self.init_marker(index=0,z_val=0)

    def init_marker(self,index=0, z_val=0):
        self.marker_object = Marker()
        self.marker_object.header.frame_id = "/camera_link"
        self.marker_object.header.stamp    = rospy.get_rostime()
        self.marker_object.ns = "mira"
        self.marker_object.id = index
        self.marker_object.type = Marker.SPHERE
        self.marker_object.action = Marker.ADD
    
        my_point = Point()
        my_point.z = z_val
        self.marker_object.pose.position = my_point
    
        self.marker_object.pose.orientation.x = 0
        self.marker_object.pose.orientation.y = 0
        self.marker_object.pose.orientation.z = 0.0
        self.marker_object.pose.orientation.w = 1.0
        self.marker_object.scale.x = 0.05
        self.marker_object.scale.y = 0.05
        self.marker_object.scale.z = 0.05

        self.marker_object.color.r = 1.0
        self.marker_object.color.g = 0.0
        self.marker_object.color.b = 0.0
        # This has to be otherwise it will be transparent
        self.marker_object.color.a = 1.0
        
        # If we want it for ever, 0, otherwise seconds before desapearing
        self.marker_object.lifetime = rospy.Duration(0)

    def update_position(self,position):        
        self.marker_object.pose.position = position
        self.marker_objectlisher.publish(self.marker_object)


class BallDetector(object):
    def __init__(self):        
        self.rate = rospy.Rate(1)
        self.save_camera_values()        
        rospy.Subscriber('/blobs', Blobs, self.redball_detect_callback)        
        self.markerbasics_object = MarkerBasics()

    def save_camera_values(self):
        data_camera_info = None
        while data_camera_info is None:
            data_camera_info = rospy.wait_for_message('/mira/mira/camera1/camera_info', CameraInfo, timeout=5)
            rospy.loginfo("No Camera info found, trying again")
        
    
        self.cam_height_y = data_camera_info.height
        self.cam_width_x = data_camera_info.width
        rospy.loginfo("CAMERA INFO:: Image width=="+str(self.cam_width_x)+", Image Height=="+str(self.cam_height_y))

    def redball_detect_callback(self,data):

        if(len(data.blobs)):

            for obj in data.blobs:
                if obj.name == "RedBall":
                    rospy.loginfo("Blob <"+str(obj.name)+"> Detected!")
                    redball_point = Point()
                    # There is a diference in the axis from blobs and the camera link frame.
                    # We convert to percent of the screen
                    # TODO: Take into account the Depth distance and camera cone.
                    rospy.loginfo("self.cam_width_x="+str(self.cam_width_x))
                    rospy.loginfo("self.cam_width_x="+str(self.cam_height_y))
                    rospy.loginfo("obj.x="+str(obj.x))
                    rospy.loginfo("obj.y="+str(obj.y))
                
                    middle_width = float(self.cam_width_x)/2.0 
                    middle_height = float(self.cam_height_y)/2.0
                
                    redball_point.x = (obj.x - middle_width) / float(self.cam_width_x)
                    redball_point.z = (obj.y - middle_height) / float(self.cam_height_y)                    
                    redball_point.y = 0.6            
                    rospy.loginfo("blob is at Point="+str(redball_point))
                    self.markerbasics_object.update_position(position=redball_point)
                
                
        else: 
             rospy.logwarn("No Blobs Found")


    def start_loop(self):
        # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped
        rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('redball_detections_listener_node', anonymous=True)
    redball_detector_object = BallDetector()
    redball_detector_object.start_loop()
```

It defines two classes, one to publish a RedSphere (MarkerBasics) and the other retrieves and converts the blob data into something compatible with space localization ( BallDetector) . Its here where all the calibration and adjustments will have to be made to have a precise representation. Because in this example the depth axis ( Y in this case ) is hardcoded, but could be calculated based on the **Blob Area**.

Another thing would be the fact that the conversion of the x,y values of the BlobTRacker to meters is done here in a very simple way, and in reallity this has to be calculated based on the focal distance and other camera details, so bare that in mind.

Hope it was usefull.

---

Originally posted by [RDaneelOlivaw](https://answers.ros.org/users/29528/rdaneelolivaw/) with karma: 281 on 2017-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0